# combining UNIQUE and EXCLUSION constraints in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, constraints

I am real beginner when it comes to databases, so any advice is appriciated.
There must be a way to combine a `UNIQUE` constraint and a `EXCLUSION` constraint in PostgreSQL.
.
The one below written by me is incorrect. (Syntactically for sure, and possible logically, too)

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- a single authenticator can belong to 1 useridx at a given time. *(so a `UNIQUE` constraint is needed)*
- however the authenticator can belong to a different useridx at a different time *(so some kind of `EXCLUSION` constraint is needed)*
- different time means outside of the interval of validform, and validuntil.

What I've tried:

```
  ALTER TABLE authentication 
  ADD CONSTRAINT lenient_constraint UNIQUE (useridx, authenticator)
  EXCLUDE USING gist(validfrom WITH =, validuntil WITH &&);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking if you can do it in a single alter table statement the answer is no.  If you are asking if you can do it against the same table, the answer is yes.  See below:

```
mydb# alter table test add unique(test);
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD UNIQUE will create implicit index "test_test_key" for table "test"
ALTER TABLE
mydb# alter table test add exclude (test with =);
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD EXCLUDE will create implicit index "test_test_excl" for table "test"
ALTER TABLE
```